# React Component accidentally share state

Tags: reactjs

[image: When I click the comment button of the second post, the comment box on the first one appear instead.]
Anyone know what is the problem? Each post is a component on its own. When I click the comment button of the second post, the comment box on the first post appear instead.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: the code is a bit long. I put it in this http://jsbin.com/jugepikado/edit?js,output

Comment: Is the code of the parent component of Post included in jsbin? I don't see it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might come across this thread later, I haven't found any valid solution by now. Thus, how I solve this is kinda a bit hacky and might cost a lot of time if your app is quite complex. I added id(not HTML id) to each post and loop through each post and check the id with the id of the element that emits the action to show comment box. If they match simply set the display of the comment box to block.

Answer (score 0):

You code showing that you have written code for like and unlike a post in you Post component. The code is common for all posts. Try to create a separate component for like section.

See this SO for a similar example: [React toggle like button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044369/react-toggle-like-button)

Comment: the like functionality works just fine. The main problem is when I click comment button of the sencond post, the comment show on the first post instead of the second post.

Comment: Yeah, I understand your problem. If use a separate component your life will be easy